# Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Users\FileName.Docx" line code works with Word VBA but not Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to insert multiple Word file in an existing Word file template using the bookmarks.
The below searches for a particular bookmark in an existing word file and inserts contents of another word file in an existing word file.
Rest of the code is working fine except the line `Selection.InsertFile FileName:=BookmarkValue`.
This line of code works in Word VBA but it is not working in Excel VBA.

Could you please help figure where I am wrong?
I have presented below simplified version of the code for your convenience.

```
Sub CreateWordDocuments3()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim DocLoc, BookmarkName, BookmarkValue, FileName As String

    Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
    Dim WordContent As Word.Range

    With Sheet3

        'Open Word Template
        On Error Resume Next                     'If Word is already running
        Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'Launch a new instance of Word
            Err.Clear
            'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
            Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            WordApp.Visible = True               'Make the application visible to the user
        End If

        DocLoc = "C:\Users\DKC\Desktop\Basetemplate.docx"

        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template          

        BookmarkName = .Cells(4, 2).Value        'BookmarkName is IndustryAnlysis in the word file (DocLoc)
        BookmarkValue = .Cells(4, 3).Value       'BookmarkValue is link to the word file to be inserted = "C:\Users\DKC\Desktop\Industry Analysis.docx"
        WordDoc.Bookmarks(BookmarkName).Select
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:=BookmarkValue ' Line code working in word VBA but not in excel VBA

        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "NewDoc" & ".docx"
        WordDoc.SaveAs FileName

        WordApp.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried combining the two lines `WordDoc.Bookmarks(BookmarkName).InsertFile FileName:=BookmarkValue`?

Comment: Also you've got a variable called `FileName` and `FileName` is also a parameter of the `InsertFile` method - try renaming the variable so VBA doesn't get confused which one you mean.

Comment: Thanks Darren for your edits. Do I need to repost the question? Yes, I tried renaming it as well but didn't work.

Comment: No, no need to repost it.  Afraid I can't offer much help - haven't really done any coding Word.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Have just noticed - you have `On Error Resume Next` to open Word, but you don't reset it afterwards so any other errors are hidden.  Add `On Error Goto 0` after Word is opened (just after the `End If`) and see if any errors pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of this post [How to use Words selection methods through Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506833/how-to-use-words-selection-methods-through-excel-vba) - or more particularly the comment by @TimWilliams at the bottom of the second answer.

The problem with `Selection` is that it will be referring to Excel.  I was trying to link it to the Word document, but it's a property of the Application:

> There can be only one Selection object per document window pane, and
>   only one Selection object in the entire application can be active.
>
> [Selection object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection)

I also pulled the CreateWord out to a separate function.

```
Public Sub CreateWordDoc()

    Dim oWrd As Object, oWrdDoc As Object
    Dim BkMkName As String, BkMkValue As String

    Const docloc As String = "C:\Users\DKC\Desktop\Basetemplate.docx"

    Set oWrd = CreateWord
    Set oWrdDoc = oWrd.documents.Open(docloc, False)

    With Sheet3
        BkMkName = .Cells(4, 2)
        BkMkValue = .Cells(4, 3)
    End With

    oWrdDoc.Bookmarks(BkMkName).Select
    oWrd.Selection.InsertFile Filename:=BkMkValue

End Sub

Public Function CreateWord(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTempWD As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTempWD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTempWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    oTempWD.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateWord = oTempWD

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateWord."
            Err.Clear

End Function
```

**Edit -**
So if you don't want to use the code I've posted your code should work by changing

```
Selection.InsertFile FileName:=BookmarkValue
```

to

```
WordApp.Selection.InsertFile FileName:=BookmarkValue
```

Comment: Nice! OP - be aware of some common words like Selection & Range between the 2 object models.

Comment: Thanks Darren.. you nailed it. This works. :) Thanks for note MacroMarc.